How to assign a type hint from the return type hint of a function
I'm using an API that uses type hints returned from functions to store information (I know that this is not recommended, I have no control over the API):
my_hint: StringProperty()

This works, but it removes the ability to use the type hint as an actual type hint.
I'm looking for a way to create a wrapper that would maintain the same syntax as the above example, but when type hinting, would assign a different, more useful type (in this case a str type).
My first idea was to do something like this:
if typing.TYPE_HINTING:
    def StringProperty() -> str: pass

my_hint: StringProperty()

However, this doesn't work, with my_hint instead being assigned the Any type.
Is there a way to do this, keeping in mind that I can't change the way the API works?

I don't quite understand what this API is doing, but maybe you could use typing.Annotated.

@mkrieger1 Unfortunately, I don't think typing.Annotated will help here.
I omitted details of the Blender API for clarity, but essentially, properties are defined on classes via the syntax above, and those classes are then registered into Blender. When that happens, Blender scans the __annotations__ attribute of the class and creates a Blender Property types according to them.
It's not a good or intuitive way of working, but unfortunately it's the way it is.
I'm looking for a way to return a usable type hint from a function, in order to maintain the same syntax.

@StrikeDigital yeah IIUUC that's the sort of thing Annotated is suppose to be for, but blender has to support it. What a mess.

(Based on a comment of yours, I assume you are using Pyright/Pylance on VSCode.)
Here's my recommendation: Forgo static type checking altogether.
StringProperty() is a call expression, which will not be recognized as a valid annotation expression by spec-compliant type checkers (including Pyright) no matter what you do at runtime.
All non-type-hint uses of the name: expression syntax are not recommended. The library/framework in question made an uncommon and unfortunate choice.

Use TYPE_CHECKING from typing for conditional imports:
    from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
    
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        from typing import Any
        StringProperty = str
    else:
        from some_api import StringProperty
    
    my_hint: StringProperty = StringProperty()

During type checking, StringProperty is aliased to str.
At runtime, StringProperty uses the actual function from the API.
This maintains the syntax and the type hint behaves as str during type checking while calling the API function correctly.
This is in more detail in PEP 484 - Typing.
Good luck!

Thanks, however, this doesn't seem to work. If I paste this code, my IDE shows the type of my_hint to be Any.
Example: https://ibb.co/j3CJzW6

Yes, you're right. I'm sorry about that; I have updated the answer..

Hmm, that now works as a type hint, but the StringProperty() needs to be called as a function in the last line in order to work with the API.

I believe the latest code edit should provide the answer.

It's close, but the type hint needs to be assigned to the result of the StringProperty() (like in the example from the question). It's non-standard, but unfortunately that's the way the API works :/. Thanks!
